# Which is better to fire SQL Query or to Process result in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `Question` and `Option` having one to many relationship. after fetching the result from the two tables the resulted array should be like this

> Question = array(
>         //result from the Question Table
>
> ```
>    Option = array(
>          //result from the Option Table
>      )
> ```
>
> );

Suppose If i want to fetch the 10 Question from database then i can do this in two ways (i think)

1. By Joining the Two Tables and fetch the data from database and the process with it PHP Loops and control.(i preferred this)
2. By fetching `Question` then firing the 10 query for `Option`. (it would be easy because we don't need to process as in case of 1)

i want to know which is better to process the Result in PHP or use SQL Queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, writing one join query is much better:

- You only make one request to the database instead of 11 (one for the question and 10 for the options). A database query is a very expensive operation - each time you make a query, a network request is made to the database.
- The database engine can optimize the query to possibly run much faster even if we disregard the difference in network roundtrip time.
- It is much easier to read, understand and modify one join query than PHP code with a query in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

`join` would far more faster and save load on server so go with joining (option 1)

Comment: Yeah, querying database is a very expensive operation

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse Join is better because this way you get only what you want on UI and load is balanced.

In second option what you do is that you fetch all the records from DB and then Process them as per your need so it TOO MUCH ...

Remember the Basic to fetch only those information only that are required.